# Printing the result of a variable again, even after it has been changed

Tags: python, pycharm

I asked a question similar to this recently, but the problem has morphed into something else. I'm making a text adventure game and have the location of the player set. You start in location 'b1' and then have the option to change it by typing commands such as "north" or "south". However, upon changing location, you see the description of both area 'b1' AND the area you just moved to. I need it to simply stop displaying the old location when you move, and also let you re-see the description if you return. Here is my code:

```
alive = 1
location = 'b1'
action = 'no_action_yet'

while alive:
    if location == 'b1':
    print("b1 location description")
    print("There is a door to the north and south, as well as paintings on the walls.")
    print('idleActions')

    if action == 'north':
        location = 'ha1'
    if action == 'south':
        location = 'a1'
    if action == 'west':
        print("west wall description")
    if action == 'east':
        print("east wall description")
    if action == 'inspect':
        print("What would you like to inspect?")
    if action == 'inspect' + ' ' + 'paintings':
        desc = False
        print("painting descriptions")
        print("One of the paintings is just an empty frame.")
    action = "no action"

if location == 'ha1':
    print("ha1 stuff")
    print("more ha1 stuff")

    action = "no action"

if location == "a1":
    print("a1 stuff")
    print("more a1 stuff")
    print("idleActions")
    if action == 'north':
        location = 'b1'
    if action == 'south':
        location = 'stage'
    if action == 'west':
        location = 'office'
    if action == 'east':
        print("east a1 wall stuff")
        print("more east a1 wall stuff")

action = input("What would you like to do? ")
```

Comment: What are you entering, what output are you expecting, and what output are you getting?

Comment: usually you have to clear all from screen and display again all text with new values. Some consoles/terminals may use special codes to move cursor in different places and then you can write text again in the same place - but it would need to know codes OR uses modules like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/curses.html), [urwid](http://urwid.org/examples/index.html) for this.

Comment: I am expecting, upon entering "north" a new description of the northern area, without the description of the previous area. As of now, I get the description of the new area as well as the old one - old one first, then the new one.

Comment: I should also probably add that is this a printed statement - therefore there is nothing to clear.

Comment: @DuckMcFuddle I read your code and it would help all of us if you included the data structure that holds your map. Where are 'ha1', 'b1' stored? Do you link them to each other using only functions like you are showing us? Any assistance the community can offer is heavily conditioned by the map data structure. (I think that's in reality your main problem here.)

Comment: They are stored as simply b1 = “”. 

Also thanks for helping out, if you’re too busy I can wait a few days.

Comment: @DuckMcFuddle I tried to write a solution that would point you in the right way without confusing you. It could have been more complicated/elaborate but that would probably be counter-productive at this point. If you can understand this solution you'll be heading in the right direction as a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aim of this solution is showing what you should be doing in terms of data structures and design choices.

Use classes to describe your data as objects, learn how to use [standard library collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) to hold your map. Use the pycharm debugger to set breakpoints and test your code (there's an icon called "Evalute expression" in the debugger that you have to learn how to use).

I included an [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) because it's the right tool for the job (just learn how to use enum.name, and enum.value don't worry too much about the rest).

This code is working, you can alter/expand upon it. (It uses 2 dictionaries for Description and Map, the key being the coordinates "a1", "b1", etc...The Map indexes a list with edges to the other nodes.)

```py
from enum import Enum


your_map = """
Example map:

   1  -  2  -  3

a  a1--a2--a3  
   |        |
b  b1       b3

"""

print(your_map)


class Wall:
    pass


class Location():
    pass


class Edge:

    def __init__(self, destination, direction):
        self.destination = destination
        self.direction = direction


class Action(Enum):
    North = 1
    South = 2
    West = 3
    East = 4
    Inspect = 5
    Exit = 6


Map = dict()


Map["a1"] = [Edge("a2", Action.East), Edge("b1", Action.South)]
Map["a2"] = [Edge("a1", Action.West), Edge("a3", Action.East)]
Map["a3"] = [Edge("a2", Action.West), Edge("b3", Action.South)]
Map["b1"] = [Edge("a1", Action.North)]
Map["b3"] = [Edge("a3", Action.North)]

Description = dict()
Description[("a1", Action.West)] = "West wall description."
Description[("a1", Action.North)] = "North wall description."
Description["b1"] = "b1 location description.\n " \
                      "There is a door to the north and south, as well as paintings on the walls."

alive = True
start_location = "b1"


def act(location):

    tmp_action = input("What would you like to do? ")

    if tmp_action in Action.__members__.keys():
        action = Action[tmp_action]
    else:
        print("Illegal action.")
        return

    if action is Action.Inspect:
        print(Description[location])
        return

    if action is Action.Exit:
        exit(0)

    direction = action

    for edge in Map[location]:
        if edge.direction is direction:
            location = edge.destination

    return location


while alive:
    print("Current location:", start_location)

    start_location = act(start_location)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I haven’t had time to try this out but I’m glad I have it here to help.